# How to store the data in cache when data load from AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When a user clicks on a button we are making an ajax call, the data came and we display the data in a div. Then user click on another button again making an ajax call and data load respective to that div, but when I click on the previous button I want that it should not make an ajax call it should pick the data from the cache. How can I do this? Please help me out on this.

Thank!!

Comment: At the time of first Ajax call, try to store all the data in to local storage using Javascript function :- `localStorage.setItem("name", "value");`

Comment: Can't you just update the ajax response header to be cachable? If you get a 304, not changed response, it's cached already iirc.

Comment: I would use localstorage or create a cookie. Both have simple implementations.  You can also hide and show the content.

Comment: Okay, I will try using localStorage. Thanks a lot for your help >

Answer (score 1):

Use localStorage, simple set the storage, and then get the storage and do a logic check.

Something like below in sudo:

localStorage.setItem("id", "stuff");

localStorage.getItem("id");

logic check

Answer (score 0):

It would much clearer if you posted your code.
Anyways, you can assign the old data to the previous ajax call from the second button now calling the second ajax request.

Comment: sorry, but your answer not clear can you please elaborate it. Thanks!

Comment: You have button1 that calls an ajax request, then another that calls a different ajax request. You cache the values of the first call using local storage or variables so that when you call the second request, your first ajax parameters are not destroyed